# AS3 moving/scrolling text up/down

Tags: actionscript-3, text

I am trying to move up and down in AS3 with the code below:
It's not working because its moving the entire container up and down not just the text.

```
Up.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, upPressed);
Down.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, downPressed);

function upPressed(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    Rules.y += 50;
}

function downPressed(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    Rules.y -= 50;
}
```

Does anyone know how to move the text only?

Best Regards,
Luben

Comment: Are you adding an event listener to a static class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the `scrollV` property of the `TextField`

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#scrollV